# ¿Porque el contextmenu no funciona en firefox?

Tags: jquery, menú

tengo una duda, tengo una funcion que cuando le doy a menu contextual se abre un pop, pero solo en Chrome, porque?

Answer (score 0):

Cada navegador es diferente y hay funciones que no soportan o las realizan de manera diferente, te sugiero que revises la documentación de la función que estas tratando de implementar para saber si funciona en todos los navegadores.

Comment: El problema es que tengo un menu contextual personalizado que lo abro con menucontext con .on() pero no funciona con Firefox. Y no se porque es:                                                     
$("body").on('contextmenu','#calender_section_bot li',function(){
        $(".context").css({"top": event.pageY + "px", "left": event.pageX + 
        "px"}).show();
 });

Comment: El código que pusiste en el comentario deberías ponerlo en la pregunta